# DateDIFF, TIMESTAMPDIFF for hours

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

For the hours I use it as date data type. When I subtract it, it just normally deducts. How can I subtract it in time format like hours? I tried put `datediff`, `timestampdiff`, but it says `invalid identifier`. Must I create any function before executing? Or did I not activate `datediff` on Oracle?

Below is my code:

```
Select S.Test_Date, E.Testno, S.Examno, S.Serialno, 'Science'
      ,DATEDIFF(hours, F.STARTED, F.ENDED) as hours From Semester S, TIME F
      ,TESTPAPERS e
Where S.Testno= F.Testno
And E.Testno =1;
```

For timestampdiff:

```
Insert Into Test (Test_Date, Testno, Examno, Serialno, Type, Hours)
Select S.Test_Date, E.Testno, S.Examno, S.Serialno, 'Science'
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(F.STARTED- F.ENDED) as hours From Semester S, TIME F
     , TESTPAPERS e
Where S.Testno= F.Testno
And E.Testno =1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, you can do arithmetic on date/time expressions easily.  Subtracting one expression from another yields the number of days (with floating-point precision) between the two expressions.

For example, `sysdate` is right now, `sysdate-1` is exactly one day ago, `sysdate-(1/24)` is one hour ago, and so forth.

So if you have two date/time items named `when` and `then`, the number of hours between them is `(when-then)*24`

No need to make it more complex than that if you're staying in Oracle. You don't need datediff, which is good because it isn't there.

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking way too complicated.